# How and in what way do content scripts share content scoped variables across different web pages?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script

There are some key parts of the [MDN content script documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Loading_content_scripts) I am having trouble understanding regarding variable scope:

> There is only one global scope *per frame, per extension*. This means that variables from one content script can directly be accessed by another content script, regardless of how the content script was loaded.

This paragraph may also be relevant (my italics) given the questions below:

> ... you can ask the browser to load a content script whenever the browser *loads a page whose URL matches a given pattern*.

I assume (testing all this has proved difficult, please bear with me) that this means:

1. The content script code will be run every time a new page is loaded that matches the URLs provided in manifest.json (in my case `"matches": [<"all_urls">]`
2. The content script code will run every time a page is refreshed/reloaded.
3. The content script code will not be run when a user switches between already open tabs (requires listening to window focus or tabs.onActivated events).
4. The variables initialized on one page via the content script share a global scope with those variables initialized by the same content script on another page.

Given the following code,

background-script.js:

```js
let contentPort = null
async function connectToActiveTab () {
  let tab = await browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
  tab = tab[0]
  const tabName = `tab-${tab.id}`

  if (contentPort) {
    contentPort.disconnect()
  }

  contentPort = await browser.tabs.connect(tab.id, { name: tabName })
}

// listening to onCreated probably not needed so long as content script reliably sends 'connecToActiveTab' message
browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(connectToActiveTab)
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(connectToActiveTab)
```

content-script.js

```
let contentPort = null

function connectionHandler (port, info) {
  if (contentPort && contentPort.name !== port.name) {
    // if content port doesn't match port we have changed tabs/windows
    contentPort.disconnect()
  }

  if (!contentPort) {
    contentPort = port
    contentPort.onMessage.addListener(messageHandler)
  }
}

async function main () {
  // should always be true when a new page opens since content script code is run on each new page, testing has shown inconsistent results
  if (!contentPort) {
    await browser.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'connectToActiveTab' })
  }
}

browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connectionHandler)
main()
```

And from assumptions 1 and 4, I also assume:

5. The existing contentPort (if defined) will fire a disconnect event (which I could handle in the background script) and be replaced by a new connection to the currently active tab each time a new tab is opened.

The behaviour I have seen in Firefox while testing has so far been a bit erratic and I think I may be doing some things wrong. So now, here are the specific questions:

- Are all of my 5 assumptions true? If not, which ones are not?
- Is firing the disconnect() event unnecessary, since I should rely on Firefox to properly clean up and close existing connections without manually firing a disconnect event once the original contentPort variable is overwritten? (the code [here](https://github.com/NiklasGollenstede/web-ext-utils/blob/d586992d086446e82a8aefa50dd3fc3e92ed3617/loader/content.js#L103) would suggest otherwise)
- Are the connect() methods synchronous, thus negating the need for `await` and asynchronous functions given the example code?

The [tabs.connect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/connect) examples don't use await but neither the MDN [runtime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/Port) or connect docs explicitly say whether the methods are synchronous or not.

Thanks for taking the time to go through these deep dive questions regarding content script behaviour, my hope is that clear and concise answers to these could perhaps be added to the SO extension FAQ pages/knowledge base.

Comment: 1) Your assumption 4 and consequently 5 is wrong. Variables aren't shared across tabs. The content scripts are just like any other web scripts so they belong to the page (the only difference is that they run in an "isolated world"). A different tab/frame will have its own environment with its own copy of the content script. 2) connect() returns synchronously but its actual work in the listeners you've attached to the port is performed asynchronously 3) There's usually no need to use port messaging unless you send dozens of messages per second in each tab.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! As a quick follow up: does this mean any variables I do want shared across pages I should store in the background script, and overwrite/update those variables by sending a message from the content script to he background script?

Comment: Yep, either that or use browser.storage.local.